# Unrecognized key word Near Fields, Terminated When Using INTO OUTFILE in mysql query

Tags: mysql, database

I have used following query for export query result as csv file..

QUERY

```
 SELECT * FROM city WHERE loc7 = 33 
INTO OUTFILE 'D://file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

This above query has Excecuted phpmyadmin 3.3.9 and mysql `version()5.5.8` and this same query has returned error for Unrecognized Keyword `FIELDS` and Unrecognized kerword `TERMINATED` in phpmyadmin 4.5.4 and mysql `version()5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2` how to solve this problem? is there any way available to overcome this prob?

Comment: it should be either d:/file.csv or d:\\file.csv

Comment: but query exceuted and i got csv file from correct path that's not matter @e4c5

Comment: then why did you post this question??

Comment: path does not matter.. query has executed mysql version `5.5.8` in phpmyadmin 3.3.9 at same query does not execute in mysql version `5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2` i asked question how fix this problem thats way i am asked that question i didn't ask question regarding path. i already mentioned this query excected and i got csv file from given path.. @ e4c5

Answer (score 0):

It could be you have FROM in the wrong position.

From the MySQL Documentation:

> SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'   FIELDS TERMINATED BY
>   ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
>      FROM
>   test_table;

Try using:

```
SELECT * 
INTO OUTFILE 'D://file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
FROM city WHERE loc7 = 33
```