# Unrecognized keyword in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadmin version 5.6.33. Prepared a query to download a table by referring

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-export-table-to-csv/

```
(SELECT 'Order Number','Order Date','Status')
UNION 
(SELECT orderNumber,orderDate, status
FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n');
```

I getting error as

```
Unrecognized Keyword FIELDS
Unrecognized Keyword ENCLOSED and so on...
```

Reference certain links

[phpMyAdmin SQL Error Unrecognized keyword near FIELDS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40525968/4881205)

[Unrecognized key word Near Fields, Terminated When Using INTO OUTFILE in mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39608147/4881205)

But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: (SELECT 'Order Number','Order Date','Status')
UNION 
(SELECT orderNumber,orderDate, status)
FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

Comment: @Anant Still shows same error

Comment: 5.6.33 might be your MySQL version, but isn't a valid phpMyAdmin version; could you look on the main page and let us know what phpMyAdmin version you have?

Comment: I done a mistake that i execute this query in sql query execution portion instead of creating Stored procedure. Once i create stored procedure with same code it works fine..

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the union as a subquery into the from clause of the select into outfile, since you want to export the entire redultset:

```
SELECT * 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FROM
    ((SELECT 'Order Number','Order Date','Status')
      UNION 
     (SELECT orderNumber,orderDate, status
      FROM orders));
```

Comment: I tryed your solution still getting same errors. And also without union just tryed simple without field enclosed, it export correctly.

Comment: Oops, placed the from clause at a wrong place. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on Shadows answer, I found the following would work in phpmyadmin's SQL editor if...

1. You alias your subquery - cause it complained about that.

**#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias**

2. The location of the file needs to be as defined in your my.ini file as defined below

> > ## To avoid warning messages  secure_file_priv="c:/wamp64/tmp"
> >
> > Note: You need to alter this in your query to suit what you are using.

Else It reports:

**#1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement**

```
SELECT * 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/wamp64/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FROM
    ((SELECT 'Order Number','Order Date','Status')
      UNION 
     (SELECT orderNumber,orderDate, status
      FROM orders)) as orders_alias;
```

And that generated the csv file. So see if that helps.

Comment: (SELECT 'Order Number','Order Date','Status') UNION  (SELECT orderNumber,orderDate, status FROM orders INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/orders.csv');  This query export the table. But if i use FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' It shows error as unrecognized keyword.

Comment: And what does the very last error state where it shows the "mysql said" message?

Comment: Do you see either the #1248 or #1290 or some other error and message?

Comment: It doesn't shows any error code. It shows error message as Unrecognized Keyword (near FIELDS), Unrecognized Keyword (near ENCLOSED).. like that, if i use those lines